# Error on Memtest86 with 2 Modules

Tags: memory, motherboard, memtest86+, memtest

When running memtest86 with new 2x4GB modules I get some million errors. Testing them individually results in no errors at all.

I already increased the voltage from 1,5V to 1,6V. I also reduced the rate from 1600 MHz to 1333MHz. I tested the modules in slot 1&2 and 1&3. But nothing resolved the errors.

RAM: 2x: GeIL 4GB 1600 CL11-11-11-28 (Model Name: GD38GB1600C11DC)

Mainboard: Gigabyte GA-F2A88XM-D3H

CPU: AMD A4 Series A4-5300

The RAM is not in the Gigabyte compatibility list: http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Memory/mb_memory_ga-f2a88xm-d3h.pdf

Do I need different memory modules?

Comment: Yes;  The memory is clearly not compatible with your hardware.

Comment: Do both fail when you use a second DIMM socket? It could be that that socket is broken. (Inw hich case even new memory will fail).